# When scraping image url src, get data:image/jpeg;base64

Tags: python, html, image, web-scraping

I was trying to scrape the image url from a website using python urllib2.

Here is my code to get the html string:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers = urllib2Header)
htmlStr = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=15).read()
```

When I view from the browser, the html code of the image looks like this:

```
<img id="main-image" src="http://abcd.com/images/41Q2VRKA2QL._SY300_.jpg" alt="" rel="" style="display: inline; cursor: pointer;">
```

However, when I read from the htmlStr I captured, the image was converted to base64 image, which looks like this:

```
<img id="main-image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQU....">
```

I am wondering why this happened. Is there a way to get the original image url rather than the base64 image string?

Thanks.

Comment: what url are you trying to scrape ?

Comment: I was trying to scrape an Amazon book page. http://www.amazon.com/Blood-Sugar-Solution-10-Day-Detox/dp/0316230022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [**BeautifulSoup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

**Example:**

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "www.theurlyouwanttoscrape.com"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

img_src = soup.find('img', {'id':'main_image'})['src']
```

Comment: This works! I was wondering that maybe I should not use htmlStr = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=15).read()  .Maybe it was the .read() method that converted the image url to the base64 image.

Comment: I am using lxml etree as the parser. Is there a way where I can still use lxml etree and still get the image url correctly?

Comment: @user1719599 - Hi there. Fast forward to 2020 and this is still an issue apparently, for me at least. Did you get it working using lxml? I am also using BS4. The answer above is too thin and does not work for me.

Comment: @Fandango68 Hi. I am not 100% on this, having not used BeautifulSoup for a while, but I would be surprised if the parser used makes any difference to the methods on the soup object(as seen above). Perhaps you should open a new question with your exact errors/issues?